# Fetching or viewing a rabbitmq results

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack

When I was trying to display rabbitmq queue details as follows, It display result as follows:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues | grep notifications.info
```

`notifications.info      37`

Now my question is that how to fetch or view those messages or information contained in notifications.info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have the admin plugin installed, you can peek inside those messages using the admin UI. Usually available on port 15672 of your rabbitmq host.

You can see if this plugin is installed by running:

```
rabbitmq-plugins list
```

Another way to receive messages from the queue is by using one of the many rabbitmq clients. E.g. the RabbitMq java client: https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html. What's your favorite programming language? Chances are that there is a client for you. Here is an overview of available clients: https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I need to do it using Python.
Could you let me know the way for the same.